Replication from VM on Hyper-V to VM on VMware
I have a Windows Server 2008 Active Directory server  on Hyper-V. I need to replicate to either Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2016 or later, on VMware ESXi.
Please how do I go about it?

I’m voting to close this question because you need an IT professional.

All AD DCs automatically replicate the directory between each other, and the virtualization platform on which they're installed is irrelevant.

Install the new server that will be the AD DC.
Promote it to a Domain Controller (via dcpromo or whatever the newest method is). It will set up replication as part of the promo process.
Add it to the list of DNS servers for your AD domain name (depending on how the other systems are set up to resolve the domain name in the first place).

Repeat to set up a second one.
When you're ready to get rid of Server 2008:

Transfer roles like FSMO to the new DC (although I think this happens automatically as part of the DC demotion in the next step).
Using dcpromo, demote the previous domain controller to a member server.



increase domain level


Spin up a Windows Server VM on your ESXi host, preferably at least Server 2016, join to your existing domain, install AD DS, promote the server to a domain controller and wait for the initial sync to complete.
View the sync status with rep admin /showrepl.
The underlying virtualization platform does not matter as long they are joined to the same domain and can reach each other over a network.

To replicate a virtual machine from Hyper-V to VMware, start by exporting the VM from Hyper-V using its "Export" feature to generate a compatible set of files. Next, convert the VM's virtual disk format from VHD or VHDX to VMDK using a tool like StarWind V2V Converter, as VMware requires the VMDK format. After conversion, create a new virtual machine on VMware and attach the converted VMDK file as the virtual disk. Once the VM is set up, adjust its hardware settings in VMware to ensure compatibility with the original VM's configuration. Finally, boot the VM on VMware and install VMware Tools to optimize its performance and enable additional features. This process ensures a seamless transition between the two virtualization platforms.

That's useful for a one time migration, but can hardly be used for proper replication.

While the OP could have been clearer, he/she does state there are different OS on the source & target.
